# how to determine if a specific div is in the view of a scrollable div parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple put: i have a scroll-able div, inside i have say 10 div's of equal height and width, div1, div2, div3..... etc div10.

If the scroll-able container is scrolled and stopped at some point, what is the fastest way to determine if div 2 (.windiv) is viewable or not?

this is basically part of a slot machine effect, I'm trying to determine if the person hit a winner or not. In this example div2 is the winner element.

I do have a few ways of achieving this, but I'm looking for a one liner type of fix. something short and fast. either JavaScript or jQuery will work.

thank you in advance.

```
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="scrollable">
<div style="height:auto;width:100%;" class="innerContainer">
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 1</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot windiv">div 2</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 3</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 4</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 5</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 6</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 7</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 8</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 9</div>
<div style="height:70px;width:60px" class="slot">div 10</div>
</div>
</div>


/*maybe something like */
<script>
if(div.windiv.position().top == div.scrollable.position().top){
alert('its a winner');   
}
</script>
/*how would i work this out? with positions() or offsets() i've hit a 
blank */
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: hi Max.. i did check this out, however this is a cordova application and this fix is a bit iffy, specifically with the program i'm using to create the app

Answer (score -1):

Why not make it a select option with an "onchange()" function?
The user can choose one option out of maybe ten. 
The winning option can be set to a function which then opens a pop up "WINNER!!". 
The rest of the options can be set to hide the select box so that the player only gets one shot at it.

```
    <select onchange="winningChoicesFunction()" id="winningChoicesSelect">
    <option disabled selected>Try your luck!</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 1</option>
    <option class="slot windiv">choice 2</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 3</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 4</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 5</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 6</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 7</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 8</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 9</option>
    <option class="noWinner">choice 10</option>
    </select>`

    <script>
    function winningChoicesFunction() {
    var winningChoicesSelect=document.getElementById("winningChoicesSelect");
         if(winningChoicesSelect.value!="choice 2"){ //if winner choice not chose
         alert("Sorry, not today buster!");          //alert not a winner
         winningChoicesSelect.style.display="none";  //Hide the slot
         document.write("Try again another day!");   //message in place of slot
         }else{                                      //if winning slot is chose
         alert("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WIN!");         //alert the winner
         winningChoicesSelect.style.display="none";  //hide slot 
         document.write("Winner winner chicken dinner!");  //show prize
         }
    }
```

Try it in action here: https://slotsexample.netlify.com

Comment: Hi Shawn.. This is a slot machine game. The spinner will stop randomly, i just wanted a function to check if the spinner is in the view or hidden in the scroll area of the parent div.. I used a different method before, but with laggy animations i had to restructure my code, now I'm just needing this function for scoring..